# Get the speed of a moving camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

Suppose the camera is moving from one position to another position, or say the camera is following a curve trajectory (by getting points on spline curve and copying the position to the camera in each render).

How can we calculate the speed of the perspective camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and dirty, you can set a camera or any other object that has a position as measure Object to monitor its speed:

```
var DebugSpeedometer = (function() {

    var lastMeasurement = 0,
        currentSpeed = 0;

    var lastMeasurementPosition = new THREE.Vector3(),
        distance = new THREE.Vector3();

    return {

        update: function( measureObject, timeStep ){

            if( lastMeasurement + timeStep < clock.getElapsedTime() ) {

                lastMeasurement = clock.getElapsedTime();
                distance = measureObject.getWorldPosition().distanceTo( lastMeasurementPosition );
                currentSpeed = distance / timeStep;
                lastMeasurementPosition = measureObject.getWorldPosition();

             }

             return currentSpeed;
        }

    };

})();

// globals
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var speedoMeter = new DebugSpeedometer();
```

In your update function:

```
console.log( speedoMeter.update( camera, 1 ) );
```

Comment: Note that this only works accurately with a small time step. If the camera is following a curve, it will 'cut corners' and give you underestimates, and the lower the time step, the more it will underestimate. Probably fine for most applications running at 60fps, though.

Comment: My actual requirement is to move the cam from 1 to another pos in a certain time eg. (0,0,0) to (100,0,100) in say 5 sec.